# Adding additional rewards on existing rewards when reward rates change

Tags: javascript, cryptography, blockchain, solidity, remix

I am working on staking contract in Solidity, and what I want to do is to add rewards on user balance when rewards rate is changed. I have this following code and when I change rate from 1 to 10, on user balance I have 10 times more rewards, and next time I change rate from 10 to 1, balance is 10 times lower. Just want to add new rewards with different reward rate on existing rewards.

```
struct StakerData {
        uint256 totalStaked;
        uint256 lastStakedTimestamp;
        uint256 reward;
    }

mapping(address => StakerData) public stakers;

function calculateReward(address user) public view returns (uint256) {
        StakerData storage staker = stakers[user];
        uint256 stakingDuration = block.timestamp.sub(staker.lastStakedTimestamp);
        uint256 calculatedRewards = staker.totalStaked.mul(rewardRate).mul(stakingDuration).div(1e18);
        return calculatedRewards;
    }
```

When new rate has been changed, it multiple with existing total staked balance without adding new rewards with different rate.

Comment: I suggest looking at how Masterchef contracts work (for example this article https://dev.to/heymarkkop/understanding-sushiswaps-masterchef-staking-rewards-1m6f).

Answer (score 0):

It is not guaranteed that all clients will receive a reward unless the calculateReward() function is executed for each address individually, which is not a good or trustworthy design.

A better approach would be to treat the contract as a pool, where tokens staked by users are calculated proportionally and stored in a mapping (which can use ERC20 directly). When assets are withdrawn, they can be calculated using (balanceOf(msg.sender) * ERC20.balanceOf(contactAddress) / totalSupply()). To add rewards or interest, tokens can be directly airdropped into the contract.

**Pseudocode for the concept:**

```
contract Pool is ERC20 {
  ...
  function deposit(uint256 amount) public payable {
    // caution: have not handle 0 total supply
    uint256 contractBalance = ERC20(stakeToken).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint256 proportion = amount * totalSupply() / contractBalance;
    ERC20(stakeToken).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
    _mint(msg.sender, proportion);
  }

  function withdraw() public payable {
    uint256 proportion = balanceO(msg.sender);
    uint256 contractBalance = ERC20(stakeToken).balanceOf(address(this));
    uint256 withdrawAmount = proportion * contractBalance / totalSupply();
    _burn(msg.sender, proportion);
    
    ERC20(stakeToken).transfer(msg.sender, withdrawAmount);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I am not clear in my question, but I want to calculate rewards based on time they staked their tokens, and based on reward rate that is given. But when I change reward rate I want to add rewards on already earned rewards with old reward rate.